# Need help will sorting date, and the height in python

Tags: python

Based on the text information, I'm required to find for each day, the lowest and highest tide in meters and print these to the screen for each day.

```
Thursday 4 January,11.58,0.38 meters
Thursday 4 January,16.95,0.73 meters
Thursday 4 January,23.68,0.02 meters
Friday 5 January,6.48,0.83 meters
Friday 5 January,12.42,0.33 meters
Friday 5 January,17.92,0.75 meters
Saturday 6 January,0.5,0.02 meters
Saturday 6 January,7.18,0.85 meters
Saturday 6 January,13.2,0.29 meters
Saturday 6 January,18.82,0.75 meters
```

the desired result is something like:

```
Thursday 4 January: 0.02 meters at lowest and 0.73 meters at highest
friday 5 January: 0.33 meters at lowest and 0.83 meters at highest
```

I managed to call the txt file and print it in the format wanted but, I have no idea how to sort it into that format.

```
aFile = open('C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\\Tides.txt')
for line in aFile:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.replace('meters', '')
    print(f": {[line]}")
```

Please help, python beginner here

Comment: Use `line.split(',')` and see what happens to `line`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `csv` and `collections` module.

**Ex:**

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

with open(filename) as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for line in reader:
        result[line[0]].append(float(line[2].strip("meters")))

for k, v in result.items():
    print("{}: {} meters at lowest and {} meters at highest".format(k, min(v), max(v)))
```

**Output:**

```
Saturday 6 January: 0.02 meters at lowest and 0.85 meters at highest
Friday 5 January: 0.33 meters at lowest and 0.83 meters at highest
Thursday 4 January: 0.02 meters at lowest and 0.73 meters at highest
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
aFile = open('tides.txt')
d = {}
for line in aFile:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.replace('meters', '')
    # After this split the line wrt ,
    line = line.split(',')
    # Assign the day as key and the the tide height as value inside value list 
    if line[0] in d:
        d[line[0]].append(line[-1])
    else:
        d[line[0]] = [line[-1]]
for k in d:
    print(k, ":", min(d[k]), " meters at lowest and ", max(d[k]), " meters at highest")
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
Thursday 4 January : 0.02   meters at lowest and  0.73   meters at highest
Friday 5 January : 0.33   meters at lowest and  0.83   meters at highest
Saturday 6 January : 0.02   meters at lowest and  0.85   meters at highest
```